# Data not getting inserted into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CreateConnectionString();
SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "[MURL_InsertTokens]";

SqlParameter ParameterTokenID = new SqlParameter();
ParameterTokenID.ParameterName = "@TokenID";
ParameterTokenID.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
ParameterTokenID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
ParameterTokenID.Value = token;
cmd.Parameters.Add(ParameterTokenID);

SqlParameter ParameterToken = new SqlParameter();
ParameterToken.ParameterName = "@Token";
ParameterToken.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
ParameterToken.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
ParameterToken.Value = token;
cmd.Parameters.Add(ParameterToken);

return true;
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MURL_InsertTokens] 
   @TokenID int ,
   @Token nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tokens)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Tokens SET Tokens = @Token WHERE TokenID = @TokenID
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Tokens(Tokens) VALUES (@Token)
        END
END
```

It's returning true but my data is not getting inserted and I don't know why.

Comment: What does your **connection string** look like?

Comment: Show the code that creates and opens the connection and assigns the connection to the command's Connection property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the procedure?

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: still not happening don't know why

Comment: @vini ConnectionString looks like an issue.  Is it attached to the SqlCommand object?  Is it opened?

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to check for the ID here

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tokens)
```

If there is at least one row in the table the insert part will never fire, just the update part

You probably want

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE TokenID = @TokenID)
```

Comment: Using * will bring all columns with all data. To satisfy `IF Exists` instead use `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tokens WHERE TokenID = @TokenID)` This way the data will be just a column with all values as 1. This would be lighter on SQLEngine.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: this statement is **plain wrong**. `SELECT *` inside a `IF EXISTS()` will **NOT** retrieve all data. The `IF EXISTS()` just checks for existence of data - it doesn't retrieve anything. Using `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...)` and `IF EXISTS (SELECT * ...)` are **identical** in performance and execution plan

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet of code does not appear to actually perform the action that you are building.  Add:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To actually perform the command.

Comment: I was not calling `ExecuteDataReader`. I had a typo in my code. I was calling `ExecuteNonReader` but was intending it to be `ExecuteNonQuery`.